# How to add/replace only modified/updated files recursively for some 2 folders?

Tags: shell, files, synchronization, file-copy

So I currently do stuff like:

```
rm -rf ../../../$CLOUD_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib_boost
mkdir ../../../$CLOUD_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib_boost
cp -r ../../../$BOOST_ROOT_DIR/$BOOST_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib/* ../../../$CLOUD_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib_boost/
```

Which sucks... So I wonder how to update/remove/add only updated files between 2 folders (in demo we have the folder with the latest stuff `../../../$BOOST_ROOT_DIR/$BOOST_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib/` and a folder with stuff that may be outdated `../../../$CLOUD_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib_boost`)?

Answer (score 6):

Rsync is your newest best friend.

```
rsync -av original/folder/ new/folder/
```

The trailing slashes are important on both; if you exclude the first, it will copy that folder as it's own folder into `new/folder/`. It's best to use the `-a` flag to preserve permissions, timestamps, etc.

Rsync will also automatically create directories as necessary to duplicate the structure.

Comment: Man, you were faster :) +1

Comment: Is `rsync` installed on most Linux unix distribs like `rm` or `cd`?

Comment: @myWallJSON Yes. While `rsync` isn't part of the absolutely minimal can't-even-boot-without-it core system like `rm` and `cd`, it's installed by default by most distributions, so you can expect it to be available on non-embedded Linux installations.

Comment: Rsync is marked ‘optional’ on Debian, i.e. not installed by default. I habitually (and explicitly) install it on every new box I deploy. However, it's marked ‘standard’ on Ubuntu. I wouldn't say you can **expect** it to be installed, I'd say your mileage may vary.

Comment: @laebshade: I'd also add `-HAXS` to `rsync` invocations unless you know for a fact there aren't hard links (`-H`), ACLs (`-A`), extended attributes (`-X`) or sparse files (`-S`). None of these are implied by `-a`.

Comment: @myWallJSON `cd` is not installed be default, it can not be installed, because `cd` can not be a program and must be a bultin shell-function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use rsync for that, in your example it will like that:

```
rsync -va ../../../$CLOUD_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib_boost/ ../../../$CLOUD_INSTALL_SUBDIR/lib_boost
```

Where -v option enables verbose mode and -a enables archive mode

You could read more about rsync on its [manual page](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)